# Mouse Keys (universal access) automatically enables itself

Tags: keyboard, mouse, accessibility, navigation

With a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04 two weeks ago, I am having an extremely annoying bug where the Universal Access Mouse Keys feature keeps enabling itself.

I notice it after I have logged in to my computer after waking it up from sleep.

I have had this bug on several other computers, usually more on Linux Mint installs.

When mouse keys get enabled, and I go to the universal access settings, it shows mouse keys as off. To disable mouse keys, I have to enable them, then disable them again.